# Using differentcss and js in different blades-Laravel10

Tags: laravel-10

I have 3 different blades (home, about, contact).

I want to use different js and css files for all 3 blades. suppose for home.blade.php i want to use home.css and home. js, similarly, for about.blade.php->about.css, about.js, for contact.blade.php->contact.css and contact. js through @extends, @section and @yield.

Comment: pardon me but, have you read [the docs for blade template](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade)?

Comment: Dear Tesa, I tried to read the page but unfortunately it goes all above the head, can you plz summarize it??

Comment: try create two files: `parent.blade.php` and `child.blade.php`. put some text then on the next line add a `@yield('placeholder')` in `parent.blade.php`. next, add `@extends('parent')` in `child.blade.php`, then add `@section('placeholder`, 'text from child')`. finally, in your route, do a `return view('child');` and take a look of the result in the browser. there are a bit of nuances on choosing between `@yield` and `@section`, but just try them and see what happen..